# Added items to registration form and get "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass"

Tags: users

I added 2 items to the user registration form Phone Number and Carrier. When I register a user or edit one i get the following error.
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$phone in user_account_form() (line 1066 of /var/www/capaug/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$carrier in user_account_form() (line 1076 of /var/www/capaug/modules/user/user.module).

Here is the code for the user registration:

```
function user_account_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;

  $account = $form['#user'];
  $register = ($form['#user']->uid > 0 ? FALSE : TRUE);

  $admin = user_access('administer users');

  $form['#validate'][] = 'user_account_form_validate';

  // Account information.
  $form['account'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'container',
    '#weight' => -10,
  );
  // Only show name field on registration form or user can change own username.
  $form['account']['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Username'),
    '#maxlength' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => t('Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('username')),
    '#default_value' => (!$register ? $account->name : ''),
    '#access' => ($register || ($user->uid == $account->uid && user_access('change own username')) || $admin),
    '#weight' => -10,
  );

  $form['account']['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-mail address'),
    '#maxlength' => EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => t('A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => (!$register ? $account->mail : ''),
  );

  //Phone Number Entry
  $form['account']['phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Phone Number'),
    '#maxlength' => PHONE_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => t('A valid Telephone number. Numbers only, no parentheses or dashes.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => (!$register ? $account->phone : ''),
  );

  //Carrier Selection
  $form['account']['carrier'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Carrier'),
    '#options' => array(t('--- NONE ---'), t('AT&T'), t('NTelos'), t('Sprint'), t('Straight-    Talk'), t('T-Mobile'), t('Tracfone'), t('Verizon'), t('Virgin Mobile')),
    '#description' => t('Your phone service provider. Select "None" for home phones.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => (!$register ? $account->carrier : ''),
  );
```

Where do I have to define those variables to get them to work?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Never, *ever* patch core like that. This is not how Drupal works. That said, you didn't specify whether you are using Drupal 7 or not; I presume you do. Instead of doing this, use the field UI module to add the relevant fields to users under Administer > Configuration > People > Profiles.

Comment: Drupal 7. ANd how can I pull the information and combine it for a list of users in a certain role? Is it possible (once they have registered) to call the phone and carrier for every user in a list?

Comment: You want the Views module for the list. You really, really need to read more documentation or a book (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010890.do) on Drupal, these are very basic questions. As for calling... put up a different question. Finally, plz accept my answer if it was useful.